# remove multiple duplicate columns sql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, addition

```
UUID    DEVICE_ID   DT
900 600        7
900 900        5
900 600        5
900 900        7
900 400        7
900 800        5
901 800        7
901 900        7
901 400        5
901 400        7
901 800        5
```

the answer should be max of dt and no duplicates of uuid and device_id
EX:

```
900 900        7
901 800        7
```

Comment: mysql OR sqllite?

Comment: select uuid,max(device_id) device_id,max(dt)dt from your_table

Comment: hi,p.salmon mysql

Comment: Hi akina that could also be answer

Comment: @Akina in uuid if 900 appears it should not appear again same to devcice_id

Comment: Imagine that there are 4 rows in source data: (900,400,3),(900,500,5),(901,400,3),(901,500,5). What output do you need in this case? and why?

Comment: @Akina i need (900,500,5),(901,400,3) . i picked (900,500,5) because dt is max than (900,400,3) and picked (901,400,3) this because 500 in (901,500,5) is already picked

Comment: If so then you need in iterational selection (next selected rows depends on previous ones). What is **precise** DBMS and its **precise** version?

Comment: i didnot get you

Comment: *and picked (901,400,3) this because 500 in (901,500,5) is already picked* Well. (900,400,3),(900,500,5),(901,400,3),(901,500,5),(902,400,3),(902,500,5). Does the output will consist from 2 rows? If so then how 2 UUID values to be returned must be selected?

Comment: *i didnot get you* Execute `SELECT VERSION();` and provide complete output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UUID ORDER BY DT DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT UUID, DEVICE_ID, DT
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: This only removes duplicates in UUID but not in device_id

Comment: ...then you should be showing the output you actually want.  My query does generate the output you showed above.

Comment: @venkatM This query provides one row per UUID - hence DEVICE_ID is unique in this group.

Comment: I gave sample output . i want a query that returns records that dont have duplicates in UUID and device_id

Comment: @venkatM Sample output is not enough. You must provide complete and detailed explanations, current ones are too partial.

Comment: @Akina lets put this way. if multiple uuid and device_id is present then consider the record with max of dt

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of Common Table Expressions (CTE) as placeholders to arrive at the correct result.

For example, the **first CTE** below selects All Devices including the maximum DT for each UUID. The **second CTE** selects devices corresponding to max DT. The **third CTE** provides the logic which removes all duplicate UUID and DEVICE_IDs, ensuring that once a DEVICE_ID has been selected, it is then ignored for subsequent UUIDs.

```
WITH AllDevice AS (
SELECT *,
MAX(DT) OVER (PARTITION BY UUID ORDER BY UUID) AS max_dt
FROM yourTable
),
MaxDT AS (
SELECT * 
FROM AllDevice
WHERE DT = max_dt
),
NoDuplicates AS (
SELECT MIN(UUID) OVER (PARTITION BY DEVICE_ID ORDER BY DEVICE_ID) AS UUID,
       DEVICE_ID, max_dt AS DT
FROM MaxDT)
SELECT UUID, MAX(DEVICE_ID) AS DEVICE_ID, MAX(DT) AS DT
FROM NoDuplicates
GROUP BY UUID;
```

See **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4de96fc8f88c3113749edde381b350d9)**

**Results**

> ```
> UUID | DEVICE_ID | DT
> ---: | --------: | -:
>  900 |       900 |  7
>  901 |       800 |  7
> ```